# How to create an action by reaching a page section in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a JQuery script which generates an action when the user reaches a section of a page.

Here is a sample of section:

```
<section class="main-section tv-section" data-section="tv" 
    style="visibility: inherit; 
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: translate(0%, -100%) matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
</section>
```

Each reached section will change the translate element to 0/-100%/-200%/-300%.

I tried to write this kind of condition but nothing happens:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if ($("section").data-section("tv").style("transform") 
        == "translate(0%, -100%) matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)") {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

I also tried to work with scrollTop() but this page doens't generates a scrollbar. Each section is reached with simple scroll down/top.

Comment: It seems that you want to do something like what [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) does with its callbacks.

Comment: Yes indeed I would like to trigger GA virtual pageviews each time the user goes to the different section.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($("section[data-section='tv']")[0].style['transform']
        == "translate(0%, -100%) matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)") {
        alert("OK");
    }
```

[see this](https://jsfiddle.net/g4n83wxk/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but unfortunately the alert is not activated when I'm going to this section :-(
Is it another way to trigger an action by going to the different sections?
Thanks